# writing file with sink in R

Tags: r, for-loop, sink

I have this code:

```
data(iris)
for (i in 1:5){
  max.print <- getOption('max.print')
  options(max.print=nrow(iris[1:4,]) * ncol(iris[1:4,]))
  sink('dframe.txt',append=TRUE)
  iris[1:4,]
  sink()
  options(max.print=max.print)

  write('                       ', file='dframe.txt',append=TRUE)
  write('###############',file='dframe.txt',append=TRUE)

}
```

My goal is to fill a .txt file in a for loop. However, when I see the output file `dframe.txt`, it looks like:

```
###############

###############                       

###############                       

############### 

###############                       

###############
```

Nevertheless, when I run manually, I can see that the expected output is written 5 times:

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
```

How can I solve this? I am using `append=TRUE` but apparently it is not enough.

Comment: Try `print(iris[1:4,])`

Comment: The problem (that @zx8754's comment fixes) is that when R is not run *interactively*, just typing a variable name (as `iris[1:4,]`) does not print it as it does on the interactive console. You have to explicitly tell R to print things to output.

Comment: @zx8754 thanks. This has solved it.